# Selenium javascript webdriver has access to javascript global variables?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access global variables using webdriver with javascript.

my code:

```
this.Then(/^I read global var$/, function (selectedElement) {
    readGlobalVar(window.location.href);
});

function readGlobalVar(varName){
return varName;
}
```

the error: 
    ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is running on node and not in the browser so when you pass `window.location.href` to your `readGlobalVar` function it fails because `window` is not defined.

If what you need is to wait until the url matches certain value you should consider [`until.urlMatches`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html#urlMatches)

Comment: Thank you, I want to have access to global variables, not href in particular, some that are specific to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [this module](http://webdriver.io/)…

The JS execution environment of Node and the JS execution environment of the browser you are controlling with Selenium are **different**. They don't share variables between them. You communicate between them by passing messages through the webdriver.

In order to read a variable from the currently loaded page, you need to use the [`execute` method](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html) to pass some JS into the page.

```
browser.execute(function () {
    return window.location.href;
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result.value);
});
```

Comment: thx, no webdriverio because of some issues with cucumberjs integration.